# JavaScript выполнить что-то только один раз при скролле

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть функция, следящая за скроллом страницы. Страница состоит из множества блоков, у каждого уникальный ID. Если какой-то блок попадает в видимую область страницы, то его ID должен записываться в массив `mass`. Проблема в том, что сейчас у меня ID блока добавляется в массив не один раз при его появлении, а постоянно при скролле, пока этот блок виден на странице. Весь код приводить не буду, приведу часть, которую необходимо подправить, а у меня не хватает знаний. Второе - если какой-то блок уходит из видимой области - его ID нужно из массива удалить. По идее это `mass.shift`, поскольку блоки идут один за одним, но не работает тоже. Заранее спасибо!

```
if( ... тут условие видимости ... ){
    // если блок стал виден         
    mass.push(id);      
}else{
    // если уехал за границы
    mass.shift(id);
}
document.getElementById("mass").innerHTML = mass; // выводим массив для просмотра
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если каждый блок имеет свой уникальный id, то перед добавлением в массив, можно использовать `indexOf`, который возвращает индекс заданного элемента. Например имеем такой массив `x = [5,6,4,7,3]`, `x.indexOf(4)` вернёт `2` - индекс элемента 4 и остановится, а если не находит заданный элемент, то возвращает `-1`.
То есть, в Вашем случае, можно написать так:

```
if( ... тут условие видимости ... ){
    // если блок стал виден       
    if (mass.indexOf(id) == -1){ //проверяем если такого элемента нет в массиве
         mass.push(id);
     }
 }
```

Comment: С первым действием все получилось, спасибо! А вот со вторым мне непонятно. Если я добавил в массив элемент ID1, затем ID2, потом ID3 и в этот момент ID1 скрывается за верхом экрана, мне же надо удалить из массива ID1, а это же shift?

Comment: @Alexashka да, не рассчитал. Изменю ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете вносить блоки не в массив, а в объект, чтобы их потом для удаления не приходилось искать в массиве. По объекту легко искать наличие ключа или удалять ключ, плюс можно легко пробегаться по нему как и по массиву если нужно. Вы избавитесь от лишней мороки над уникальностью ключей.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev спасибо за ответ, но я в js начинающий, хорошо хоть пока с массивами разобрался чуть-чуть.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так: `mass[id] ? null : mass.push(id)`

Answer (score 0):

Вот с объектом вместо массива:

```
let obj = {}; // наш объект-хранилище

if( ... тут условие видимости ... ){
    // если блок стал виден         
    obj[id] = true;
}else{
    // если уехал за границы
    delete obj[id];
}
```

// выводим для просмотра:

```
document.getElementById("mass").innerHTML = JSON.stringify( obj, null, 4 );
```

// проверяем содержится ли уже:

```
if( obj[id] ) ...
```